# Unable to create Spring multi-module project in Intellij IDE ultimate 2020.3

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I am new to maven , spring , Intellij IDEA. I am trying to create a spring multi module project and while I was following the documentations there is an option call "Packaging" or "Type" to change the project packaging as "pom".

This is a picture from one of the document.

[image: Took from net]

But in my IDEA (ultimate 2020.3) There is no option to change that. This is my IDEA.
As I am new to this IDEA, is there any way to get that option?
Or are there any best ways to create spring multi module project?

Please help. I have searched for solution for this more than 2 days.

[image]

(I am using ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: There is a type Present in second SS also. What exactly is the requirement. If you want multiple Modules you have to create it one after other.

Comment: Yes.. Inorder to create parent project the packaging should be "pom". In the second screen shot pom is not available. I have seen a lot of videos in YouTube and all of them have the option to change it to "pom"

Comment: Maven creates your POM.xml. Just create it with Maven Option Enabled.

Comment: Or if it doesnt create packaging as POM , you can manually override it by  <packaging>pom</packaging>

Comment: In pom.xml there is a dependency called packaging. In order to create a parent module wee need to have than packaging as pom( normally it will be like jar).. In IDEA there need to be an option to change that jar as pom. So that only it will be easier to create multi module project..

Comment: I don't want to edit it in the pom.xml file.. I really want to k ow why there is no option available in the IDEA 2020.3.  Because I have wasted 2 days of searching this

Answer (score 1):

The **Maven POM** option you think generated a Maven aggregator (a `pom` packaging) does not actually do this. It only creates a `pom.xml` file without a template project (directories and a source code). The **Maven Project** option creates the `pom.xml` file and the source code.

[image]

As for your original question about how to create a multi-module Maven project - create an empty Maven project type, set its packaging to a `pom` and then add Spring Initializr projects to in using File | new | Module action.

Comment: There is an option call Packaging (after Language) . In there we can select as pom no?  But I really want to know why the option you are having is not in my version. I activated ultimate version to generate mavan and spring projects easier.   But at last I created a module with default setting and then in the pom.xml file I changed the packaging as pom.

Comment: Can I know what version you are using? And are you using ultimate or normal

Comment: `But I really want to know why the option you are having is not in my version.` This option has been deprecated and removed from the IDE ui interface in the latest versions. Why do you need it?

Comment: I need it to create spring multi-module project. I found having an option like this will make the creation little bit easier.  Now I create a spring project and then I change the package in the pom.xml as "pom" and manually deleting the src folder. Then I create the child modules.

Comment: `I need it to create spring multi-module project.` that option was not creating the pom packaging.